# Evaluating anything as a Boolean

Tags: lua, boolean

I am cleaning up another person's code, and I really want to be sure of this before I make a large number of replacements.  The LUA documentation states that a Boolean evaluation will see anything other than false or nil, as true.  Is this true of more complex objects such as classes and tables?

There is a class Monitor, which takes in a function and acts based on the boolean return of that function.  It is called like this:

```
Monitor(middleFunction,otherparams):hook("doThing",otherstuff)
```

The function **middleFunction** has this:

```
function middleFunction(monitor,arg)
    return otherFunction() ~= nil
```

My understanding is that, since **middleFunction** is returning a boolean based on whether **otherFunction** is not returning nil, I could cut out the entire class and just **pass otherFunction to Monitor.**  If the function returns nil, it will evaluate as false, and if it returns anything else it will evaluate as true:

```
Monitor(otherFunction,otherparams):hook("doThing",otherstuff)
```

Is this a safe change?  In some cases I have no visibility into either otherFunction or Monitor, but I know that **otherFunction returns either a table or nil.**  Are there any possible cases where it might not evaluate properly if I make this change?

Comment: It looks like `middleFunction` was created to convert result to strictly boolean values (true/false).  The `Monitor` might rely on this.  Can you look into `Monitor` to see how it checks the value?

Comment: I have no visibility into Monitor at all, sadly.  It looks like it's possible Monitor accepts only boolean values, and as long as that's possible I can't make the change :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unsafe, the boolean evaluation only works for a single expression,

```
function Monitor(f, p)
    if f(monitor, arg) then
    end
end
```

But it doesn't work for relational operators, this example only accepts the boolean value `true`

```
function Monitor(f, p)
    if f(monitor, arg) == true then
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I needed!  Since I can't get into Monitor, and it's possible it could be written to require middleClass, I sadly can't remove it.